# Make a newly created terminal visible (VSCode)

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm working on creating a new extension for VSCode using typescript. I've got almost everything working but I'd like to make the terminal I've created (using `vscode.window.createTerminal()`) visible. I've been able to send text to run commands and I thought that `.show` would work, but it did not. Is there something that I'm missing?

```
if (!hugoTerminal) {
  hugoTerminal = vscode.window.createTerminal({
    name: 'Hugo Server'
  });
}

let execCommand = 'hugo server ' + previewArguments + ' -s ' + vscode.workspace.rootPath;
hugoTerminal.sendText( execCommand );

hugoTerminal.show;
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't comment so I just post this here. Show is a function so you need the ().

```
show(preserveFocus?: boolean): void
```

https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#Terminal

Don't worry we all make that mistake. Congrats!

Comment: Well, that makes me feel stupid. Since I wasn't getting any errors, I just thought it wasn't working or was doing something else I didn't understand.

Many thanks!